# Display post status drop down by user capability

Tags: wordpress

I want to prevent post status by user capability. Like 'draft' and 'pending' status display when author is logged in and 'publish' status display when editor is logged in.

Comment: Ok. we know what you want. now what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish, pending, draft' );
} else {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
}
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     CONTENT

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply
  But i want to prevent post status by user capability in add,edit post in admin side.

Comment: So you must use `current_user_can( $capability, $args );`
instead of `is_logged_in()`
You can read about capabilities here [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities)

Comment: Hi Sir,
I want to prevent post status drop down on publish panel in add new post in wp-admin. Above code for display data for particular post status.

I hope you understand my question.

Please guide me.

Comment: Ok, so editor can do everything with post but author can only publish it but not save as a draft, yes? 
My first idea is to write custom css for WP Admin and include it only in user is author, not editor. Look [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/customizing-the-wordpress-admin-adding-styling/) . For editors you must use one simply css line: `#post-body .misc-pub-post-status, .quick-edit-row-post fieldset label.inline-edit-status { display: none; }` . The first one will hide status info on post edit page, the second - on the list of post when you click "quick edit"

Comment: Hi Mr. Shemek.
 I want code for that not css plz.

 In my website 5 status (Pending,draft,corrected,readytopublish and publish). in post. Author can save as pending and draft,translator can save as corrected and pending and editor can save as pending,Ready to publish. Admin can save all. This is my requirement. so i have to prevent post status dropdown in add new,edit post page :wp-admin. 

I hope you understand my requirement.. Please guide me.