# Restrict user role to change only some order statuses in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I would like to restrict access by role to certain order statuses from the dropdown list in woocommerce. I have tried in functions.php child theme the code on [Restrict woocommerce order status by role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375749/restrict-woocommerce-order-status-by-role) but cannot get it to work and do not have enough rep to post a comment.

https://prnt.sc/mpfl3b is the screenshot of what is showing - I would like shop manager (or a custom role created) to only be able to mark an order as processing or on-hold with no other options visible from the dropdown.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please remove this being too broad as it is not. It is very specific and a very specific answer was given which works. This answer was very very helpful to me, and just labelling things like this (not the first time) too broad does not help anyone looking for this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked answer code will not work for what you want. Instead try the following:

```
// Admin orders list: bulk order status change dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'filter_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function filter_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $new_actions = [];
    foreach( $actions as $key => $option ){
        // Targeting "shop_manager" | order statuses "on-hold" and "processing"
        if( current_user_can('shop_manager') && in_array( $key, array('mark_on-hold', 'mark_processing') ) ){
            $new_actions[$key] = $option;
        }
    }
    if( sizeof($new_actions) > 0 ) {
        return $new_actions;
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Admin order pages: Order status change dropdown
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'filter_order_statuses');
function filter_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow === 'post.php' || $pagenow === 'post-new.php' ) {
        $new_order_statuses = array();

        foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $option ) {
            // Targeting "shop_manager" | order statuses "on-hold" and "processing"
            if( current_user_can('shop_manager') && in_array( $key, array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing') ) ){
                $new_order_statuses[$key] = $option;
            }
        }
        if( sizeof($new_order_statuses) > 0 ) {
            return $new_order_statuses;
        }
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you Loic that worked by changing "administrator" to whatever role needs to restriction needs to apply to the dropdown on. I changed lines 7 & 27 to the relevant roles. I assume this is okay? In my case "doctor" but could be any role.

Comment: Thank Loic, it does answer it. For when others view this you just need to change administrator to the role you wish to apply these privileges to or change the status themselves. Flexible. Can't upvote not enough rep yet.

Comment: Similar Question: can you help please?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904370/prevent-user-role-from-changing-woocommerce-order-status