# Apply CSS Rule to woocommerce Product BACKEND page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

We try to apply a certain css rule to a product backend page not the frontend page.

But there are 2 types of pages one which is when you click create product and one when you click edit product.

We need to apply the css rule to both of these pages.

We achieved half of the answer by determining part of url when we click add product in the backend by the solution below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'bbloomer_apply_css_if_url_contains_string' );

function bbloomer_apply_css_if_url_contains_string() {

$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if(false !== strpos( $url, 'post_type=product' )){
    echo '<style type="text/css">
         #ovaem_sectionid { display: none !important }
         </style>';
} 

}
```

We hope if there is a thing like `(is_Product)` but for the backend can be used for both when adding a new product or when editing an existing product page to apply this css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<body>` contains `.post-type-product` class, use it as the first selector

```php
function my_custom_css() {
    echo '<style>
        .post-type-product #ovaem_sectionid {
            display: none !important;
        } 
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css' );
```

Comment: but does this will make it apply in other posts that are not post type product ?, because we have the same class #ovaem_sectionid in other custom post types which we don't need to hide..

Comment: other post types do not contain the .post-type-product <body> class. 
An id is of course a very specific selector, does the tag with the id also contain a class? otherwise it is better to use .post-type-product .class-name